Ubuntu 24.04 freezes randomly and does not recover without force shutdown
I just installed a version of ubuntu 24.04 LTS as the main operating system, so far it has only given me problems, as it freezes suddenly on several occasions, on all occasions without any exception, I had to turn off the computer to bad, and I have no idea what it could be, currently activate the parameters GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=“quiet splash nomodeset processor.max_cstate=1”, I tried reinstalling the OS but does not work, my specs are:
GPU: Gigabyte GeForce RTX 2070 SUPER WINDFORCE OC 3X 8G
CPU: MD Ryzen 5 3500X
RAM : Kingston Fury Beast KF426C16BB/8 (2 x 8GB | DIMM DDR4-2666)
PSU: Corsair CV Series CV550 (CP-9020210-WW) (550 W)
MOTHER BOARD: ASUS PRIME B450M-A II
SSD M.2 NVME: Kingston A2000 1 TB (SA2000M8/1000G)

and the truth is that I am ignorant on the subject, I was reading problems associated with the cpu and problems associated with the gpu, but the truth is that I can't find the real problem because I can't read the logs or where to get them from.

I was having very similar problems and also tried reinstalling with Linux Mint LM22.  I could not get the Nvidia 550 driver to work, my system kept locking up.  So I decided to just run the nouveau driver for a while, but every time I shut down the system it took a ridiculously long time.  I tried the above answer with the GRUB command line options but it did not help.  I finally tried the below (found it on a different forum) and it actually worked and my system is much more stable and shuts down quickly now.
sudo apt install nvidia-driver-550-open
Hope this helps somebody.

The specs of my system are different than yours, but I had the same symptoms and experimented with a few grub parameters. Adding these to GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT finally solved the problem for me:
kernel.watchdog=1 kernel.soft_watchdog=1 nmi_watchdog=1

